# Declaring a value using a function inside a variable

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to declare a variable value using a function like the following.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = $('#div').click(function(){
    x = 25;
  })
  alert(x);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'>The Div.</div>
```

I don't say this is the way i use, But just an example, Since i want to define the variable value case i pressed the div to be `25`, And if i didn't click the div it would be empty `''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$().click(function) returns the jQuery object it operates upon.  So if you want to set the x to the value, you'd have to do it like below.  Just know the alert outside of the click event would always alert blank.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = '';

  $('#div').click(function(){
    x = 25;
    alert(x);
  })
  alert(x);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'>The Div.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting x as an empty variable in the beginning, then using an event handler to change it. And if you immediately alert, after the handler is set, you will have no time to click before the alert. You will have to wait for that click to do something with x.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x;
  $('#div').click(function(){
    x = 25;
    alert(x);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'>The Div.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the scope of your variable, and you don't want to assign the value of the click handler to x.

- [more info about jQuery's click](https://api.jquery.com/click/)
- [info about scope in javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

  ```js
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var x = '';
        $('#div').click(function(){
          x = 25;
        });
        alert(x);
      });
  ```

  ```html
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <div id='div'>The Div.</div>
  ```

In the above example the scope of the value of x is limited to the `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` block.  So outside of that, x will be undefined.  The `$('#div').click(function() { ... });` has the ability to modify x since it's scope is also limited to the document ready callback.

If you want to alert the change of the value of x when you click the button you will need the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = '';
  $('#div').click(function(){
    x = 25;
    alert(x);
  });
});
```

What this is doing is when `#div` is clicked the value is changed to 25 AND you are alerting the changed value.